# Are there any free Silverlight PDF controls?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, pdf-generation

Hey, I'm trying to both create and display PDFs in an OOB app I'm trying to make as part of a hobby. Does anyone know of any good controls for creating and displaying PDFs in Silverlight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this one http://silverpdf.codeplex.com/?